# How do I pass table data from a template over to Django on a button/submit click?

Tags: python, html, django

My template has a search field that brings up results on a table. In the table, with each result, I'd like to place a "+" Button that will allow the user to save that row of results to their profile.

Here is what the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WdC5.jpg

The relevant chunk of my template:

```
<form action="{% url 'foodlog:detail' foodlist.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2 }}
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>


{% if foodResults %}
<table>

    <th>Food</th>
    <th>Calories per 100 grams</th>
    <th></th>

{% for x, y inResults %}
    <tr>

    <td>{{ x }}</td>
    <td>{{ y }}</td>    
    <td> <input type="submit" name="add" value="+" method = "post"> </td>

    </tr>>
{% endfor %}

</table>

{% endif %}
```

Relevant chunk of my view:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'add' in request.POST:
             #psuedo code
             #object.create(food=[buttonrow, firstheader], calories=[buttonrow, secondheader])
             #object.save()
```

I also don't know why those '<<<<<' appear on the page, as shown in the image.

Comment: What is the issue? Is this about `<<<<<` ?

Comment: there could be a git conflict which might not have been solved or seen

Comment: The main issue was figuring out how to submit data from a row to Django. nigel222 pointed me to a good direction in how to solve that, but I would like to know why those arrows appear above my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what nigel222 suggested, except I put the data under the 'name' attribute and kept 'value' as '+'. request.POST has the name as the 2nd key

html

```
<table>

{% for x, y in Results %}
    <tr>

    <td>{{ x }}</td>
    <td>{{ y }}</td>    
    <td>    
        <form action="{% url view %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" name="{{ x }}|{{ y }}" value="+"> 
        </form> 
    </td>

    </tr>>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

view

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if '+' in request.POST.values():
        pair = [key for key in request.POST.keys()][1].split("|")
        #pair will be a list containing x and y
        object.create(thing1=pair[0], thing2=pair[1])
        object.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is that clicking a button on a row of the table will submit data from that row to Django, then you will need some Javascript to do `onClick` processing to insert data from the row into the form fields before submitting. Alternatively, instead of `value="+"` fill in something unique to each row. For example, make `Results` a queryset returning, say, `Product` objects, make the template `for` loop iterate over these objects, and then you can do `value="{{product.id}}"`. You then pull this value directly out of `request.POST` in your view function (and don't forget to validate that it does indeed correspond  to an existing product before it gets to crash your code! )