# Django: select all data from a row in a html table and use them in a view

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to both django and web development.
The task is to run a script when pressin a button using the data contained in the specific row of an html table.
So if i clik on the second button "Run script" it uses all the data in that row (8888, 2020/06/21 06:00) in a separate script to performe some task. [image]

Currently my html file looks like this:
There are 2 sections one for uplading the information that goes in the table one the table which displays them

```
<h1>Approach Path KML Generator</h1>

<h2>Generate the KML file here:</h2> <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    
    <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'approach_path_receptorsKML:Proejct Creator' %}'">Upload</button> </form>

<h2>Projects Available:</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Date KML</th>
            <th>Time KML</th>
            <th>Date-Time Uploaded</th>
            <th>Run The Conversion</th>
            <th>KML File</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for project in latest_project_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ project.project_ID }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.date_kml }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.time_kml }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.upload_time }}</td>             
                <td>
                    <button method="post" value="collect data" name="{{ project.project_ID }}|{{ project.date_kml }}|{{ project.time_kml }}|{{ project.upload_time }}">Run script</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ project.download_doc }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download KML File</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </tbody> </table>
```

And this is the view I have created:

```
def ProjectCreator(request):
    form = DocumentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
        elif 'collect data' in request.POST.values(): 
            values = [key for key in request.POST.keys()]
            print(values)                    
        else:form = DocumentForm()
```

I have tried to use this guide ([How do I pass table data from a template over to Django on a button/submit click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863105/how-do-i-pass-table-data-from-a-template-over-to-django-on-a-button-submit-click)) however, I have been insuccesfull.

If anyone can spot the mistake I have made and give me some explanation I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have incorrect HTML layout. Button itself doesn't do anything - in order to send POST request, it should be in `<form>` tag. Try following:

```
{% for project in latest_project_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ project.project_ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ project.date_kml }}</td>
            <td>{{ project.time_kml }}</td>
            <td>{{ project.upload_time }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button value="collect data"
                            name="{{ project.project_ID }}|{{ project.date_kml }}|{{ project.time_kml }}|{{ project.upload_time }}">
                        Run script
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ project.download_doc }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download KML File</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

This will work, but I doubt this is great way of achieving this. You can just send `project.pk` with POST request and fetch `project` in view. This way you can be sure user will not send incorrect/malicious data with request. It is especially important since your code will run script based on data.